# Convert vector tile (MVT) location to Latitude, Longitude coordinates

Tags: javascript

I have a Geojson data file which is converted from **mvt vector file**. However the coordinated are not stored as latitude, longitude so I need help converting between the mvt coordinate system to google maps latitude, longitude using javascript.

Let me know if you need more information.